# Fetching and filtering data from multiple JOIN by JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, hql, jpql

I have 3 entities which bound with each other.
**Group**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Rating> ratings;
}
```

**Rating**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_student")
    private Student student;
}
```

I need to get the group by id with all students with their rating which have a date between.
I trying these cases to solve the problem

```
 @Query(value = "select g from Group g INNER JOIN g.students s ON g.id = :id INNER JOIN s.ratings r ON r.student.id = s.id and r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd GROUP BY g.id")

 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Group g INNER JOIN student ON g.id_group = :id RIGHT JOIN rating on student.id_student = rating.id_student and rating.`date` between :dateStart and :dateEnd GROUP BY g.id_group",nativeQuery = true)

 @Query(value = "select g from Group g WHERE g.id = :id and g.students IN (select s from g.students s JOIN s.ratings r where r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd) GROUP BY g.id")

 @Query(value = "SELECT g from Group g JOIN g.students s ON g.id = :id JOIN s.ratings r on s.id = r.student.id and r.date between :startMonth and :endMonth")
```

But none of these not filtering ratings as must.
Locally with this query all works

```
SELECT * from `group` JOIN student ON `group`.id_group = 1 LEFT JOIN rating on student.id_student = rating.id_student and rating.`date` between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28';
```

Anyone have idea whats wrong or how to conver local query to JPQL?

**UPD**
To avoid the questions about the date I use the same logic with the date to get all rating between date.
**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "Select r from Rating r where r.student.id = :studentId and r.stageOfApprove = :stageOfApprove and r.date between :startMonth and :endMonth order by r.paragraph.id asc ")
    List<Rating> findAllRatingsByIdStudentAndStageOfApproveGreaterThan(@Param("studentId") Long studentId, @Param("stageOfApprove") Integer stageOfApprove,
                                                                       @Param("startMonth") Date startMonth, @Param("endMonth") Date endMonth);
```

**Service**

```
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
DateTime minDays = currentDate.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime maxDays = currentDate.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
ratings = ratingRepository.findAllRatingsByIdStudentAndStageOfApproveGreaterThan(studentId,1,minDays.toDate(),maxDays.toDate());
return ratings;
```

Comment: How do you provide the date ? As `Date` objects or as strings ? Can you try to pass the dates as Strings properly formatted ?

Comment: "But none of these not filtering ratings as must." - what do you get instead? Nothing or too many groups? Can you provide some sample input and expected output? And did you try to have the SQL that the JPQL queries are transferred into logged?

Comment: Try the following query please: `select distinct g from Group g join g.students s join s.ratings r where g.id = :id and r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd`, i.e. move the conditions to the where clause and use `distinct` instead of `group by`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle as object, I have a query which filters rating between dates with the same logic as I try to use in this case and that query works as i expect.

Comment: @Thomas without @FetchMode(SUBSELECT) in Group i have a duplicated students  without filtered ratings

Comment: Did you try the query I suggested? That should return the groups that match the query. Your last comment might also indicate that you then expect the groups to contain a filtered list of students only - if so then please note that this doesn't work. That list will _always_ contain all students in a group (btw the code you posted lacks the mapping from student to group which `mappedBy = "group"` but I assume it's in your actual code since otherwise you'd not be able to load the entities at all).

Comment: @Thomas i have in Group `mappedBy`